# Calculate minimum and maximum value in the same rows usign awk

Tags: bash, awk, max, average, min

I have data set looks:

```
A 10
A 12
A 13
B 10
B 25
B 66
B 80
C 2
C 3
```

I am able to calculate using AWK average values per the same rows (using array). I would like to add to my script minimum and maximum values. Is there any idea?

My script:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{v[$1]+=$2; n[$1]++}END {for (l in n) {print l "\t" v[l] / n[l]}}' > out.txt
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Same column? You have just one element in the row.

Comment: Just add more arrays, for example `avg[]`, `min[]` and `max[]`.

Comment: Yeah in the same column. If there is only one value just print the same value for min and max. Lets say - D 10 ---> min=10, max=10..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code should be trivial to read

```
$ awk       '{k=$1; v=$2; sum[k]+=v; count[k]++} 
  !(k in min){min[k]=max[k]=v} 
     min[k]>v{min[k]=v} 
     max[k]<v{max[k]=v} 
          END{for(k in sum) print k,min[k],max[k],sum[k]/count[k]}' file |
  column -t

A  10  13  11.6667
B  10  80  45.25
C  2   3   2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding your code:

```
$ cat foo.awk
{
    v[$1]+=$2 
    n[$1]++
    if(min[$1]>$2||min[$1]=="") 
        min[$1]=$2
    if(max[$1]<$2) 
        max[$1]=$2 
}
END {
    for (l in n) 
        print l, v[l] / n[l], min[l], max[l] 
}
$ awk -v OFS="\t" -f foo.awk foo.txt
A       11.6667 10      13
B       45.25   10      80
C       2.5     2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be creating 2 more arrays: one for the max values, and another for the min values.

Comment: Yeah I am still try to figure out how to add array for min and max.. still have some errors...

Comment: @Geroge the question would be much better if you showed the attempts you made there and the errors you're getting